# How to divide each row of pandas dataframe by dictionary value?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which has two columns `sales` and `year`. I have created a sales by year dictionary, `time_series_sales`, which groups `df` by year and then sums all the sales for that year

```
# df = 
+-------+------+
| sales | year |
+-------+------|
|  1980 | 0.4  |
|  1981 | 2.1  |
|  1980 | .... |
+-------+------+

time_series_sales = dict(df.groupby(['year'])['sales'].sum())
print(time_series_sales)
>>> {1980.0: 11.379999999999999, 1981.0: 35.77000000000001, ...
```

I now want to divide, element wise, the `sales` column by the corresponding `year` value in `time_series_sales`. The code below works, but uses an explicit for loop, so it's slow.

```
for row,index in df.iterrows():
    df.iloc[row,1] = df.iloc[row,1] / time_series_sales[df.iloc[row,0]]
```

I was hoping there was some pandas functionality I could use here, or maybe use `.apply` to apply a function to `df` to do this, but I haven't been able to do it. Something like the below would be great.

```
df['sales'] = df['sales'] / time_series_sales[df['year']]
```

but I just get a `TypeError` with this code

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

So, is there some way to do this without using an explicit for loop, maybe using pandas functions/methods?

Comment: Instead, why not use `df['sales'] / df.groupby('year')['sales'].transform('sum')`?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much @Zero